# Angular create a template on the fly

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading alot about the route provider and how you can load different templates by specifying the url path.

Is there a way where instead of providing a path to template, we could programatically generate a view on the fly and attach it to the controller?

Comment: you can create an angular directive and make the changes dynamically

Comment: any resource where I could get some more insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can dynamically create a template in a directive using [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

here's another example:  http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/.

I'm not sure how you do that using just the router though.  I think you need to add more context to you're question.

Comment: Haha I just landed on that article 5 mins back!
But hey .. Thanks a ton :)